# django form action is not redirecting to app url

Tags: django, forms

I am following the article in the djangobook on Forms:

```
http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07.html
```

the search url in the article doesn't redirect it to my app(book) url. Instead it goes to 127.0.0.1:8000/search, it should have been 127.0.0.1:8000/book/search

Comment: please, provide some code.

Comment: You should consider checking your urls.py, the redirects in your views.py, the URL tags in your templates example: {% url 'books.views.search' %}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should specify the url on the form tag

```
<form action="/book/search/?" ...>
```

And make sure it points to the right address / view /url.py and all that